# How to use geom_bar() to create two grouped columns in R

Tags: r, geom-bar, geom-col

There has got to be an easy way to create one set of grouped bars for aware column and a another set of grouped bars for serious column with the individual bars within each group being the value for the respective regions. Final image should look similar to attached image.
Thanks!

[data I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihcmv.png)

[Image I'm seeking approximately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z20J1.png)

```
by_region <- country_obs_df %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  summarize(
    #region_avg_gdp = GDPperUS,
    #region_avg_co2 = CO2emi,
    #region_avg_pop = Population.2008,
    region_avg_aware = mean(Aware),
    region_avg_serious = mean(Serious)
  )
ggplot(by_region) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(fill = Region, x = Region, y=region_avg_aware), position = "dodge") +
  labs(y = "Percent")
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`.  May be `library(dplyr);library(tidyr); df1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Region) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Region, y = value, fill = name)) + geom_col()`

Comment: The above code captures one of the grouped bar charts I seek but it's for only the aware data. I also want the serious data

Comment: Please try with the code in my comments

Comment: That creates a stack bar chart with the regions as x-axis values and aware % stacked ontop of serious %.

Comment: You need to change it to "dodge".  Posted a solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to pivot to 'long' format then, use `geom_col`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
by_region %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -Region, names_to = 'region_avg') %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = region_avg, y = value, fill = Region)) +
         geom_col( position = "dodge") +
         labs(y = "Percent")
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
by_region <- structure(list(Region = c("Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Europe (North America)", 
"Europe (Oceania)", "Latin America & Caribbean"), region_avg_aware = c(39.9, 
60.9, 88.3, 96.6, 97.3, 63.8), region_avg_serious = c(82.3, 76.3, 
67.7, 71.1, 78.2, 93.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

For sure, it is possible, you have to reformat your data to long so that you have the required variables in a row format in order to be plotted. Here the code using the data screenshot you shared:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- data.frame(Region=c('Africa','Asia','Europe','Europe (North America)',
                          'Europe (Oceania)','Latin America & Caribbean'),
                 region_avg_aware=c(39.9,60.9,88.3,96.6,97.3,63.8),
                 region_avg_serious=c(82.3,76.3,67.7,71.1,78.2,93.8))
#Plot
df %>% pivot_longer(-Region) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,group=Region,fill=Region))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        panel.grid = element_blank())+
  xlab('Variable')
```

Output:

[image]