# Plotting series of factor variables side by ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, count, aggregate

I am trying to plot a series of variables, which are collected in two-time frames. The structure of data is something like this, the number of observations is 9700, the class is factor.
[Please see the structure of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TExL6.png)

[image]

I want to plot a barplot like this[I will have a list of the sbs base on each wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvTwP.png).

[image]
I have used aggregate function and dplyr, but I could not make a proper structure for the data.

I am very happy that can you help me with it.

Thank you,

Comment: These might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64146274/how-to-use-geom-bar-to-create-two-grouped-columns-in-r & https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tung suggested, you can put your data into long format, and use `position_dodge` with the plot so bars are next to each other in the plot. Here is an example.

Using `tidyr` `pivot_longer` you can put columns that start with "sb" into long form. Then you can `filter` out rows where the value is zero. `unite` will combine names - such as `sb_1` and `x` to become `sb_1_x`.

In this format, it is easier to plot. Use `geom_bar` to create the bar plot, and use `position_dodge2` to put bars next to each other with different `wave` values. The use of `preserve = "single"` keeps the bars the same width (in cases where one `wave` has zero count).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("sb")) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  unite(sb, name, value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sb)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = wave), position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"))
```

**Plot**

[image: bar plot]

Comment: You are the best .

Comment: Could you help me with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64884680/ordering-x-axis-using-ggplot . The order is changed if my variable is more than 10. Thank you

Comment: Could you please let me know, what function I should use if I want to have percentages than counts? It means for each bar I need the  (number of x / total sample in each wave).

Comment: ```new_data %>%
    group_by(wave) %>%
    mutate(total.wave= sum(count)) %>%
    group_by(total.wave, sb) %>%
    mutate(per=paste0(round(100*count/total.wave,2),'%'))
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("sb_")) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  unite(sb_,name, value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sb_)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = wave), position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")))``` and I got this error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `total.wave`. x invalid 'type' (closure) of argument i Input `total.wave` is `sum(count)`. i The error occurred in group 1: wave = "first".

Comment: Thank you, I  did that, and bars do not appear in the plot. I have made a new question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939338/plotting-series-of-factor-variables-side-by-side-and-have-the-percentage-on-y-ax   Please check that and I will upload the picture there.